# Unable to run TestNG test case in Eclipse with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have written below code to open a site in chrome browser and verify its title. but when using `System.setProperty()` to set the `ChromeDriver` Path, it gives me syntax error and when I commented the line I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property..
```

My Code :

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class FirsttestNGFile {
    String BaseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Automation Jars\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); -- If I comment this line, I get Illegal state Exception for chromedriver path; if not commented , I get syntax error
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  

    @Test
    public void verifyHomePageTitle() {     
    driver.get(BaseURL);
    String ExpectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String ActualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedTitle, ActualTitle);
    driver.quit();          
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have also tried Project->Clean; but this didn't not help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define `System.setProperty` Globally.
Use below code and try:

```
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void browser(){
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\CP-SAT\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
 driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
}

@Test
public void verifyHomePageTitle() {     

    String BaseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    driver.get(BaseURL);
    String ExpectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String ActualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedTitle, ActualTitle);
    }

@Test
public void a() {
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=6PDbV-qTAZHT8gecr4qQBA");    
} 

@After
public void close(){
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

If you are using `Junit` then use `@Before` or If you are using `TestNG` then `@BeforeTest`.

Reply me for further query.
Happy Learning. :-)

Comment: Be careful: the TestNG equivalent of `@Before` is `@BeforeMethod` and not `@BeforeTest` which is called before a group of classes. `@BeforeSuite`-> `@BeforeTest` -> `@BeforeClass` -> `@BeforeMethod`

Comment: I was now trying to run multiple test cases, but since I have put declaration of Chromedriver in @beforeTest, I am getting compilation error for driver used in every test and when I redeclare the driver, it opens a new chrome window every time. I want that I get to declare driver only once and can be used in my test methods each time

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager which will make the job for you:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update chrome driver path in environmental variables path and then try to use below code in your script

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```